Is there a name for this paradox and how is it refuted?
tl;dr - how can heaven be paradise if those there are aware of the suffering of others in hell?
I think that creates a paradox. My logic goes like this:

Heaven is for followers of Christ. It's presumably pleasant. Christ refers to it as paradise.
Christ's 2nd commandment is to love your neighbor. This includes even your enemies.
The type of love we're talking about cares deeply about the plight of others. It shares other's pain, regardless of whether the pain is deserved.
Not everyone goes to heaven. That leaves the rest in hell, where there is eternal suffering.
How does the plight of the damned not weigh on the minds of the saved? How can paradise be paradise if it is not shared by everyone?

I could contrive an argument against each point, but everything I come up with seems biblically incorrect: No one could go to heaven, no one could go to hell, hell isn't really that unbearable, heaven comes with it either an understanding of why the suffering isn't upsetting or it comes with an ignorance of the suffering of others, once a non-follower passes your obligation to love them expires with them. None of these seem satisfactory.
The point about enemies isn't necessary for the paradox. Plenty of Christians have non-Christian family members. What solace is there for them?
Does this problem have a name? What are the answers to it?

There have already some Questions along similar lines; for example, https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/84687 or https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/31962/53502.

There is no paradox. That's why there is no name for it. It is God who will judge all things and his judgment is just. For he is God and there is none other.

The weakness is point 4, which makes more than one non-biblical assumption. ¶ A similar but simpler version is "How can a loving and forgiving God inflict eternal suffering?"

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

This is one of the most common questions new believers ask themsleves that have very close relationships to their family.. No need to close it. But nothing requires refuting just understanding.

Perhaps item 3 could be revisited as I'm not convinced it represents a biblical definition of love.  See Leviticus 19:17 and John 8:24.

I added the bit about family as an afterthought. I think Luke 6:32-36 challenges us to love all as family. Whatever grief we have about lost children we should feel for the wicked.

A previous question on this topic had the OP referring to such feelings as "survivor's guilt", and admitting that it was based on emotions. The question was closed. This site requires questions to be scoped to particular groups, to avoid raising general topics that attract myriad (often conflicting) views. With regard to hell, this comes under the theological heading of "The Last Things", so in order to give a brief answer to a massively complex matter, I will quote from this book approved of by many in the Reformed Protestant school of belief, and, indeed, this is a study-book for students of theology.
Points relevant to this question arise when understanding the purpose of Christ's return - his "second coming" - which will usher in the Day of Judgment and Resurrection. The purpose of this is:
"1. The final vindication of Jesus Christ as Lord and King...

The completion and glorification of the church...

The righteous judgment of the living and the dead...

The final overthrow of all  powers of evil...

The establishment of 'a new heaven and a new earth' in which 'righteousness will dwell'." In understanding be men, T.C. Hammond, p. 181, Inter-Varsity, 1977 reprint


Misunderstanding any of those five reasons for Christ's return in glory will be bound to result in misunderstanding the reason for the existence of hell. But, to cut to the chase, here is the book's explanation of the Judgment, which follows the resurrection, and when the redeemed and the reprobate alike will receive 'the things done in the body'.

"The appointed Judge is Christ Himself. The reasons for, and the
principles of, judgment are clearly delineated in Scripture. The
verdict is declared to be absolutely 'righteous'. There is a finality
about the statements concerning the execution of justice which is
intensely solemn, and yet satisfying to the moral sense. At last wrong
shall have received its just recompense...

The Principles of the Judgment of Non-Christians - the following are plain:

(i) The absolute justice of God (Gn. 18:25).
(ii) There will be allowance made for the varying degrees of
privilege, both of opportunity and responsibility. Compare our Lord's
words regarding Sodom (Mt. 11:24).
(iii) The determining factor in the case of those who have heard the
gospel is acceptance or rejection of Christ.
(iv) In the case of the heathen, who have not had the privilege of the
gospel, it is suggested that they will be judged on the grounds of the
light they had (Rom. 1:19-23; 2:14-15).

The Results of Judgment - The actual words of the final doom are given by the Lord Himself in Matthew 25:41 and 46. There would seem to
be no valid reason why the statements should not be taken at their
face value. But two erroneous opinions have arisen which have received
extensive acceptance.

(i) The universalists claim that the separation of good and evil will
not be everlasting, and that finally all men will be reconciled to
God.
(ii) The annihilationists teach that the souls who are finally
condemned to separation from God will be annihilated and not reserved
for eternal punishment. This view speaks of 'conditional immortality'
...Two things are certain. It seems to be abundantly clear that
Scripture holds out no hope of a second probation for those who have
neglected or deliberately misused their present opportunities.
Irretrievable loss awaits the deliberate rejecter of Christ at the
throne of judgment...
Several passages refer plainly to this final consummation of all
things (Is. 51:6; 2 Pet. 3:7-13; Rev. 21:1). The references imply not
annihilation but a complete destruction of all links with an old and
sinful world and the transformation of the old into a new world, never
to know sin and corruption. As with the resurrection of the body,
there is both continuity and discontinuity between the old and the
new, which is represented both as issuing out of the destruction  (Is.
13:9-13; 2 Pet. 3:10-13; cf. Heb. 12:25-29), and as consisting in the
'conversion' and liberation of creation (Is. 11:1-9: 35 cf. Lk. 7:22;
Rom. 8:21).
...Paradise lost in Genesis becomes paradise regained in the
Revelation. Between them lie the fascinating story of the promise of,
and preparation for, redemption, the work of Christ, and the progress
of the redeeming work from Pentecost to the coming of Christ. (Ibid.
pp.189-192)

If none of that helps to open up the righteousness of the final judgment that will result in many suffering the anguish of what is generally called "hell" (though the Bible uses more exact language than that), perhaps that could be due to not yet having a grasp of the utter righteousness of God, as shown from Genesis to Revelation. To suggest that the final judgment of the damned is wrong, or unfair, or 'over-the-top', is to suggest that God is wrong unfair, and (therefore) neither righteous nor holy in all his ways. Surely the need would be for sinners like us, to seek God's view of the matter, not our own earth-bound, sin-tarnished one?
Jesus came to lead repentant sinners to the Father; in him we see the Father (John 14:6-11). He came to give life everlasting in glory to those trusting in the promises of God and in what he did to secure our release from slavery to sin and death. Studying the life and words of Christ, and following him in faith, will enable us to understand our need to "Seek first the kingdom of God, and his righteousness, and all these things shall be added unto you" (Matthew 6:33).
It is the righteousness of God that is the fundamental point in the matter of a final judgement that will see many lost for all eternity in an anguish beyond words. That, I suggest, is the only way to resolve what you see as "a paradox".
As for the final question posted, "What solace for Christians who have non-Christian relatives?" Those relatives may yet come to saving faith in Christ, and Christians have the responsibility of pointing them to Christ as Saviour and Lord, by word and deed, before he returns. Further, these promises of God hold good: "All that the Father giveth me shall come to me; and him that cometh to me I will in no wise cast out...  My sheep hear my voice, and I know them, and they follow me: and I give unto them everlasting life; and they shall never perish, neither shall any man pluck them out of my hand. My Father, which gave them me, is greater than all... The Lord knows them that are his...  (John 6:37; 10:26-29 & 2 Timothy 2:19)
P.S. Nobody exemplified that ‘type’ of love in Logic #3 more than Jesus Christ did! He supremely shared the pain of others, regardless of pain being deserved or not, suffering in their stead so that God’s righteous punishment on sin was born by him, in his body, so that they would not suffer that wrath. Those who spurn what Christ did are showing contempt for the love of God, in Christ, to us who deserve it not.

There's a lot to digest. 2 quicks:
"He supremely shared the pain of others, regardless of pain being deserved or not, suffering in their stead so that God’s righteous punishment on sin was born by him, in his body, so that they would not suffer that wrath." - Exactly! The ideal follower of Christ (it seems to me) would feel the same way and not be at peace until they could take the suffering on behalf of the damned.
"Surely the need would be for sinners like us, to seek God's view of the matter, not our own earth-bound, sin-tarnished one?" Yes, but ultimately it (should?) seem just.

@PaulJackson To say Christians would "not be at peace until they could take the suffering on behalf of the damned" would require us to be sinless humans and wholly God, as was Christ. We cannot do what he did to spare anyone the wrath of God but we are commissioned by him to share the good news of how alienation from the holy God stops when sinners repentantly put faith in what the one Mediator between God and man did. We proclaim the gospel of salvation and pray. By word and deed we witness to Christ's witness. That's our remit. God is just and our justifier: Romans 8:30-33.

@PaulJackson "ultimately it (should) seem just".  I believe that it will.  Believers are being conformed to the image of Christ and when they see Him they will be like Him.  I expect that when we are like Him we will hold His view of justice.  We currently are not like Him and so should not expect our current judgements on the topic to be just, as He is.  We must simply trust in the Word that we have.  "Will not the God of all the earth do right?".

There's no paradox as a believer has no family, and such kind of worries are also impossible in heavenly bodies. The command of loving your enemy is commonly misunderstood to promote pacifism and capitulation. It means having a loving attitude with enemies even during the time of war, not being ruthless if some enemy needs water.
The command of loving your neighbour is about solidarity and impartiality, it cannot supersede the first commandment of loving God. In fact, we have clear instructions of hating our families compared to the love of God. Thus, those who love their families and loved ones more than God or his justice, will not even deserve heaven to be miserable due to their families being in hell.
The born again concept of conversion implies cutting all ties with humans, including family and friends and ancestry, to become like a newborn. Jesus also did not recognise his mother and brothers (Matt 12:48-50). A newborn or born again man denounces all worldly affairs and relations, thus, hating his family and the world; he is dead to his family.

Sanhedrin 68b:10
Rather, the verse is speaking of the robbery of a convert, who is treated like a newborn child and considered to have no ties to his natural parents or relatives.


I deleted that confusing part.

Maybe I shouldn't have mentioned family. I think Luke 6:32-36 makes it clear we are to love enemies like family.

That kind of hyperbolic teaching is not on par with the commands like loving your neighbours as yourself, where the neighbours are your lovers/wellwishers. It is actually teaching not to be ruthless to enemies in the same line as the OT passages like Rom 12:20-21. The key cause underlying the ques may be a faulty doctrine that determines one's fate to heaven/hell based on ritualistic religion/faith alone, which may cause the pain in others for the injustice of innocent being sent to hell. Or it's complete opposite, injustice, where you want universalism (no justice for the deeds)

Clearly the justification for kindness in Rom 12 is at odds with Luke 6. However, the command in Rom is entailed by the command in Luke. If you love your enemy like your family (and loving neighbors, like even the wicked do), you would come to their aid even when they are at war with you. Why reject Luke, who is passing along  Christ's teaching, based on something from Paul that doesn't even contradict (the command doesn't contradict, but the motivation does)?

I didn't reject it and none of those cancel the commands of hating the world and the sinners. Read in context. Jude 23.

The scriptures do not fully explain how heaven will work and how God will wipe away every tear from our eyes. Therefore we can only draw on commen sense principles and other related topics.
For example:

The angels underwent the same problem, they would have loved each other and God would have loved them all including the devil, but when they fell they are no longer objects of love.  The goodness that was in them, the resemblance of God in them, was lost altogether. Therefore it does not seem to make sense that the good angels are sad about their lost brothers now. They are sad at the fact that they in the [past sinned but not sorrowful over Satan now, worring about the pain he will ensdure when thrown into everlasting torments.

We actually joyfully choose sorrow among friends and family already on earth for the greater joy of experienceing God‘s love and glory over our friends and family.  Why can we be happy when our fellow humans are commited great sins? Similarily, howwas Noah and his family able to be happy after the flood? Somehow they could. Somehow we can but we do not fully understand how the Spirit gives us joyful hope. Why do some Christians suffer the loss of their freinds and even family and yet can rejoice?  Similar principles will reasonably continue in heaven. Even when the loss of friends and family is greater, yet the joys greater still. We do not full understand how and why we feel today what we feel, even less can we theorize about a future glorious state that has not been revealed to us. All we have been told in that the joy we have now is only small taste of that joy we will have then.

Sinners now retain a glimpse of the image of God even though they have fallen spiritually but that will not continue into the afterlife. This may be why we find people likeable and want to have friends and family because God smiles upon us through their likeable traits. Even evil people have some likeable traits or at least enjoyable appearances to us, even if they are like ‘a golden ring in a pigs snout’. (Prov 11:22).  However, after the final judgement all those likeable traits will be vanish and sinners will be no different than demons. Possibly our good memories will be preserved but they might no longer be attached to those souls that are no longer recognizable to us. A demon is no longer identifed with its past angelic state.


In any case we can be sure heaven is filled with eternal joy and gladness because it is God that created joy and knows how to pour it out upon his beloved and most treaured saints, of who all believers are titled. This does not talke away now the angusih of Fathers and Mothers concerned for their unbelieving children, or the sorrow of godly children praying for their unbelieving parents but faith can cling on to what has been promised and also continue to hope for the salvation of their dear loved ones.
